# framerate-independent movement (c++ and SDL)

Tags: c++, sdl

I am learning about gameloops in c++ and I have created code that can make movement (of a rectangle) independent of the fps.

Like so:

```
delta_time = (SDL_GetTicks64() - last_frame_time);
last_frame_time = SDL_GetTicks64();



int player_speed = 1;
// player control of box
const Uint8* currentKeyStates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
if (currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) rec_player.x +=(int)(delta_time) * player_speed * 0.5;
if (currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) rec_player.x -=(int)(delta_time) * player_speed;
if (currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_UP]) rec_player.y -=  (int)(delta_time) * player_speed;
if (currentKeyStates[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN]) rec_player.y +=(int)(delta_time) * player_speed;
```

This appears to work as intended (I have tested with various SDL_delay settings and the rectangle appears to move with the same speed even with low fps.

However as soon as I want to scale the movement speed (as seen in the line with the 0.5 miltiplicator at the end to a lower than 1 value, it breaks, the rectangle will move at a lower speed, however at very uneven speeds.

I also had to cast the thing to int because moving left would be slower because of a rounding error or something similar.

How to get the scaling of the speed to work? I think the issue lies with it being int and multiplying it by 0.5 appears to make the end result 0. Because the delta_time in program is usually 1-2 (miliseconds).

How to scale the speed of the object while retaining the synchronicity to the time?

Comment: is the x coordinate a float?

Comment: Either maintain the position as a floating point value, which may or may not be a good idea depending on the rest of your game, or accumulate the delta position in a different floating point variable and subtract whole integers from it to apply to the actual position.

Comment: Are you aware of this article: https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/ Since I don't see an issue with your code, I could describe what I'm doing in my gameloop that does not exhibit such bugs, but it's pretty much just based on that article. I think floating-point for positions is a sensible default, unless you know that your type of game will have issues with that.

Comment: The rectangle coord are all int. I have modified the code following your suggestion and changed it to float, and removed the casting to int. The problem is the same.

Comment: Hard to comment on your changes since we cannot see them, but it doesn't really have anything to do with SDL, it is just math. Here's an example you can fiddle with that accumulates over time at various deltas and speed multipliers and works as expected.  https://godbolt.org/z/YbdjKv1ch

Comment: You can use a [SDL_FRect](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL3/SDL_FRect) and [related functions](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RenderCopyF) for floating-point rendering.

Comment: @SafelyFast

That fixed it. I replaced all the rect with frect and it appears it is now able to handle the tiny fractions of deltatime being multiplied with the rect variables.

I think internally the code of Rect would insist on keeping everything int, because I have attempted turning my functions that create rects to use floats for the variables, however it appears to have quietly ignored it.

Thanks for the advice  everyone!